# jenv: is there a command that indicates which plugins are enabled?

Tags: jenv

The `jenv plugins` command will, I believe, show you all available plugins.

Is there a `jenv` command that indicates which plugins are actually enabled?

Comment: Tried `jenv plugins --enabled` ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that worked!  Is this documented anywhere?  If you add an SO answer, I'll award it. (and please link to the docs if there are any).

Comment: Honestly? I never even used jenv before - I just installed it for this question because I thought it would be a sane default for showing enabled plugins and it worked :D

Comment: @LesHazlewood `jenv help plugins` does not document it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to list all plugins is by running `jenv plugins --enabled`